# Angular busca array

Tags: angular

Estou com um problema para buscar os dados de um array

```
buscarDados(cep: string, uf: string, cidade: string): CEP[] {
    this.storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("enderecos"));
    return this.storedNames.filter((endereco: CEP) => 
        endereco.cep.indexOf(cep) !== -1 ||
        endereco.uf.indexOf(uf) !== -1 ||
        endereco.cidade.indexOf(cidade) !== -1);
  }
```

Quando informo por exemplo um CEP que existe no array com uma cidade ou UF inválida e feita a consulta.
O que não pode acontecer.
Por exemplo se digitar 11111-111, Campinas e SP num array que só tem 11111-111 e SP válidos a busca e feita.
Não deveria deixar fazer essa busca pois SP não existe no array.

O que está errado no meu método de busca?

Comment: Se você precisa que as três condições sejam atendidas, precisa usar `&&` em vez de `||`.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:

```
  buscarDados(cep: string, uf: string, cidade: string): CEP[] {
    this.storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("enderecos"));
    return this.storedNames.filter((endereco: CEP) => 
        endereco.cep.includes(cep) &&
        endereco.uf.includes(uf) &&
        endereco.cidade.includes(cidade));
  }
```

Comment: Já tentei dessa forma só que no caso busca por todos os campos digitados. No caso preciso informar um ou mais campos válidos para fazer a busca